# apc.rfc1867 not enabling through php.ini

Tags: php, apc

I am trying to turn on using the below in my php.ini file

```
apc.rfc1867 = on
```

I'm doing this to allow me to build a progress bar for file uploads.

I am hosted on a Godaddy shared server and am not able to edit the php.ini directly, so am creating a new one and adding the above code to it. This doesn't seem to be having an effect though on activating this option. i've also used

```
<?php
echo 'apc.enabled = ' . ini_get('apc.enabled') . "\n";
echo 'apc.rfc1867 = ' . ini_get('apc.rfc1867') . "\n";
?>
```

and was initially returned with

```
apc.enabled = 1
apc.rfc1867 = 0
```

but now i've randomly been returned with

```
apc.enabled = 
apc.rfc1867 =
```

and through checking phpinfo() i can no longer see any of the apc options.

does this mean APC is now disabled? why would this happen?

Comment: I suspect that you're creating a php.ini in the wrong place, but troubleshooting that is outside the scope of this site. Contact your hosting provider's support team for help.

Comment: i can see the the php.ini file is in the right place as when i use phpinfo(), it shows the file that I have uploaded. But it would appear that when i add the `apc.rfc1867 = on` line to php.ini, apc appears to disappear completely?

Answer (score 0):

For GoaDaddy shared use php.ini not php5.ini in your root level folder.
apc.rfc1867 = 1

Comment: can you please elaborate?